# when using jQuery Validation I can't use my custom class

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I have a form with radio buttons which I want to validate

the problem is that I already have class for the radio buttons , therefore when i add the class required it does not work, but when I remove my class it does work.

here is the code:

html

```
<form id="ratingform" >
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-2" > <span style="color:#1eb682;">وضوح الشرح </span> </div>
<div class="col-md-8 ol-md-pull-5">
<input  type="radio" value='1' name="Clarity" id="Greenradio1" class="css-checkbox required" /><label  id="Greenradio1" for="Greenradio1" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='2' name="Clarity" id="Greenradio2"  class="css-checkbox" /><label id="Greenradio2"for="Greenradio2" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='3' name="Clarity" id="Greenradio3" class="css-checkbox" /><label id="Greenradio3" for="Greenradio3" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='4' name="Clarity" id="Greenradio4" class="css-checkbox" /><label id="Greenradio4" for="Greenradio4" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='5' name="Clarity" id="Greenradio5" class="css-checkbox" /><label id="Greenradio5" for="Greenradio5" class="css-label"></label>
</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<!-------    Helpfulness   ------>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2" style="color:#f9a765"> التعاون  </div>
<div class="col-md-8 ol-md-pull-5">
<input type="radio" value='1' name="Helpfulness"  id="Orangeradio1" class="css-checkbox required" /><label  id="Orangeradio1" for="Orangeradio1" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='2' name="Helpfulness" id="Orangeradio2"  class="css-checkbox" /><label id="Orangeradio2"for="Orangeradio2" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='3' name="Helpfulness" id="Orangeradio3" class="css-checkbox" /><label id="Orangeradio3" for="Orangeradio3" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='4' name="Helpfulness" id="Orangeradio4" class="css-checkbox" /><label id="Orangeradio4" for="Orangeradio4" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='5' name="Helpfulness" id="Orangeradio5" class="css-checkbox" /><label id="Orangeradio5" for="Orangeradio5" class="css-label"></label> 
</div> 
</div>  
<br> <br>
<!-------   Kindness  --->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2" style="color:#e72a71;"> السهولة  </div>
<div class="col-md-8 ol-md-pull-5">
<input  type="radio" value='1' name="Kindness"  id="Redradio1" class=" css-checkbox required" /><label  id="Redradio1" for="Redradio1" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='2' name="Kindness"  id="Redradio2" class="css-checkbox" /><label  id="Redradio2" for="Redradio2" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='3' name="Kindness"  id="Redradio3" class="css-checkbox" /><label  id="Redradio3" for="Redradio3" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value= '4' name="Kindness"  id="Redradio4" class="css-checkbox" /><label  id="Redradio4" for="Redradio4" class="css-label"></label>
<input type="radio" value='5' name="Kindness"  id="Redradio5" class="css-checkbox" /><label  id="Redradio5" for="Redradio5" class="css-label"></label>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br>
      <input class="submitRating" style="overflow:auto;" type="submit" value="ارسل">
     </form>
```

javascript:

```
$("#ratingform").validate();
```

I also tried to write the rules like this

```
 $("#ratingform").validate({
 rules: {
 // simple rule, converted to {required:true}
 Helpfulness: "required",
 // compound rule

 }
 });
```

any help will be appreciated

Edit:

I figured the problem .. it is from the css because I added 
display:none; to the radiobutton to style it my way ,and the validation doesn't work if the element is hidden or display is none

Comment: @Sparky that's how i done it check the code

Comment: Ok, what's not working?  Your code is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/3tLq4/

Comment: @Sparky that's odd it does not work on my code when I add the class !! code it possibly be the css ??!

Comment: No, can not be CSS.  Are you wrapping in a DOM ready event handler?  Are you getting any JavaScript console errors?

Comment: @Sparky no JavaScript errors .. however, the other form elements( like options) who their validation works fine when I use  the ready event handler it stops working therefor i don't use it

Comment: @Sparky I figured the problem it is from my css because I added 
display:none;
to the radiobutton to style it my way , but the validation doesn't work if the element is hidden or display is none  .... Thank you  for your help

Comment: In the OP, you never mention anything about validating something that's hidden.  If that's the case, just use the plugin's `ignore` option to enable the validation of hidden elements.  Exactly as, `ignore: []`  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/3tLq4/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"I added display:none; to the radiobutton to style it my way ,and the validation doesn't work if the element is hidden or display is none"*

If that's the case, enable validation on hidden elements using the `ignore` option.

```
$("#ratingform").validate({
    ignore: []  // sets the option to ignore nothing.  Hidden elements will be validated
});
```

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/3tLq4/2/